# get HP Printer Serial Number via CMD

Tags: vba, vbscript, cmd, printers

Is there any way to gather Serial Number info for HP Printers on Windows using only the CMD?
I don't need a third party tool. What I need is to be able to query them from CMD.
For the workstations I use the [wmic /node:COMPUTER bios get serialnumber] command to get what I want.
I was wondering if there's a way, a script of some kind that could perform the same action.

Thanks

Comment: This needs more information. Do you want VBA? VBScript? Command line? This isn't at all clear right now what you are asking.

Comment: I need VBA, as I mainly work in excel. But I would settle for anything that could gather the Serial Numbers of them network printers.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find an option to include the serial number as it is not supported by the vbscript Win32_Printer class, however you may be able to retrieve unique information from this script.

[Win32_Printer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhds6k80%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Option Explicit

```
Dim objWMIService
Dim objItem
Dim colItems
Dim strComputer
DIm intPrinters

strComputer ="."


    ' Pure WMI Section
    Set objWMIService = GetObject _
    ("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer")



    ' On Error Resume Next
    For Each objItem In colItems

        If(objItem.name = "HP") Then

        WScript.Echo (objItem.name)
        WScript.Echo (objItem.Description) 
        WScript.Echo (objItem.DeviceID)
        WScript.Echo (objItem.DriverName)

        End If  

    Next

'Release Memory
Set objItem = Nothing
Set objWMIService = Nothing
Set colItems = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Thank you for your input here, but this does not meet my needs. I need to gather the Serial Numbers of the Printers in a way ...

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to the party, but...

This should work at least for HP Office Jet (tested with HP Office Jet 4500). I don't have access to any other models but I can imagine that it works for any network-managed (HP) printer.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%a in ('curl "http://192.168.0.000/index.htm?cat=info&page=printerInfo#" 2^>nul ^|findstr /rc:" *CN"') do set "SN=%%a"
echo Serialnumber is %SN%.
```

This depends on the printer to be manufactured in China (Serial number starts with `CN...`

The question explicitly asks for a `cmd` solution. With any language with proper HTML or REGEX support, there are surely better (safer) solutions (not depending on `CN...`).

Also, the `curl` command might be subject to improvement (first time I used it)

the relevant section in the HTML looks like:

```
                  <tr>
                     <td class="info">
                        
                        Product Serial Number
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        CN000A000A00AA
                     </td>
                  </tr>
```

I extracted the link to the info page from `curl <printer-ip>`, which gave me

```
<body onLoad="window.top.location.href='./index.htm?cat=info&page=printerInfo'">
```

(which surely can be used to get the correct page with different models)

(Note: `curl` is now available with WIN 10, so this probably won't have worked back in 2014 "out of the box")